# What is the idea of using str_rot13

Tags: php, string

Well, I can't understand what is the purpose of [str_rot13](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) php function.
I understand how it works but can't figure out in which situations is suitable for use.
Can you give me some examples?

Comment: When you want to print something that humans cannot immediately read but can easily do so if they want to. For example, plot spoilers. Also, when you are making a historical review of crypto.

Comment: There are many usage examples on the man page http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php

Comment: He's not asking for examples, he's asking for real world application. He linked the man page in the question.

Comment: The [`ROT13` entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) has some information on its uses.

Comment: As a side note incase it wasn't immediately obvious, 13 isn't an arbitrary number. It's half way to 26. We have a 26 chararacter alphabet, so applying the function to a string twice will return it to its original value.

Answer (score 13):

> In cryptography, a Caesar cipher is one of the simplest and most
>   widely known encryption techniques.
>   -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

There is nothing more to it, it's easy to implement and having it in the library wouldn't do harm. It can be used for spoilers (instead of a "show spoiler" button), for trivial encryption (a client-side config file, a hint in an online game), as fancy way to encode your email (avoid spam bots) or just for toying around. However, serious use is highly discouraged [(unless you plan on bombing something)](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/22/ba_jihadist_trial_sentencing/).

Answer (score 0):

As already told, you can use it for spoilers in forums.

You can also use it as an example of an [idempotent unary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence):

```
rot13(rot13( someString )) = someString
```

For each `someString`.

Comment: What you mean by "spoilers in forums" ? Sorry but english is not my native language.

Comment: @dofenco A spoiler is something that can ruin your anticipation; like someone telling you the outcome of a movie or a cheat that could impair your ability to play a game passionately.